# Enum-based State Machine, Dagger2 injection of state handler

Tags: java, enums, dagger-2

I'm trying to create a state machine that uses an enum to specify the states. Since there are a lot of states and the logic implemented by each is pretty complex, I wanted to associate each state with a state handler that will be defined in a different class. Each state handler would implement a common interface (or extend a common abstract class), but each one might have its own set of injected dependencies that the others might not need. So far, something like this....

StateHandler Interface:

```
public interface StateHandler {
    void onActivation();
    void onDeactivation();
}
```

Example StateHandlers:

```
@Singleton
public class DefaultStateHandler implements StateHandler {
    @Inject
    public DefaultStateHandler(SomeDependency someDependency) {...}
    /** implement onActivation, onDeactivation and state specific logic **/
}

@Singleton
public class OtherStateHandler implements StateHandler {
    @Inject
    public OtherStateHandler(SomeOtherDependency someOtherDependency) {...}
    /** implement onActivation, onDeactivation and state specific logic **/
}
```

StateManager implementation:

```
@Singleton
public class StateManager {
    private StateType stateType = StateType.DEFAULT;

    @Inject
    public StateManager() { }

    public void changeState(StateType newStateType) {
        if (stateType != newStateType) {
            stateType.getStateHandler().onDeactivation();
            stateType = newStateType;
            stateType.getStateHandler().onActivation();
        }
    }
}
```

Enum Definition:

```
public enum StateType {
    DEFAULT (/* not sure what to do here */),
    OTHER_STATE (...);

    private StateHandler stateHandlerInstance;
    public getStateHandler { return stateHandlerInstance; }

    StateType(/* not sure what to do here */) {
        /* assign stateHandlerInstance */
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is... how do I inject the specific instances of the state handlers when declaring their associated enums? Or if that isn't possible, is there another way of specifying the state handler class for each enum, and then (either in the constructor or by the time its first needed), get the associated state handler instance?

Comment: Did you have a look at `@IntoSet` and `@IntoMap`? https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html

Comment: I tried, but honestly it went over my head and I wasn't even sure if that was going down the right path. Was hoping that someone might be able to fill in the gaps with an example designed for this use case. But I'll try again and post the solution if I figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally thinking I needed to inject the state's handler instance into the state enum definition. However, since injection requires public constructors and enums use private constructors, I don't think that approach is feasible.

As mentioned in the comments above, the solution was to use map multibindings.

First the enum StateType is simplified:

```
public enum StateType {
    DEFAULT, OTHER_STATE
}
```

Now we need a dagger MapKey interface specific to this enum type:

```
@MapKey
@interface StateTypeKey {
    StateType value();
}
```

Next we need a dagger module which will have provider functions for each StateType / StateHandler combination:

```
@Module
public StateTypeHandlersModule {

    // @Provides @IntoMap               // Syntax for dagger >= 2.9
    @Provides(type = Provides.Type.MAP) // Syntax for dagger <= 2.8
    @StateTypeKey(StateType.DEFAULT)
    StateHandler provideDefaultStateHandler(DefaultStateHandler handler) {
        return handler;
    }

    // @Provides @IntoMap               // Syntax for dagger >= 2.9
    @Provides(type = Provides.Type.MAP) // Syntax for dagger <= 2.8
    @StateTypeKey(StateType.OTHER_STATE)
    StateHandler provideOtherStateHandler(OtherStateHandler handler) {
        return handler;
    }

}
```

Its unfortunately a lot of boilerplate code, which is why I'm using a separate module just for the handlers, and including that in the higher-level state machine module. Note that if you declare two provider functions with the same StateTypeKey, the second handler is ultimately available in the injected map.

Finally, we can inject the `Map<StateType, StateHandler>` into the StateManager:

```
@Singleton
public class StateManager {
    private Map<StateType, StateHandler> stateHandlerMap;
    private StateType stateType = StateType.DEFAULT;

    @Inject
    public StateManager(Map<StateType, StateHandler> stateHandlerMap) {
        this.stateHandlerMap = stateHandlerMap;
    }

    public void changeState(StateType newStateType) {
        if (stateType != newStateType) {
            stateHandlerMap.get(stateType).onDeactivation();
            stateType = newStateType;
            stateHandlerMap.get(stateType).onActivation();
        }
    }
}
```